# Best practice for loading test data in separate python files for model training and evaluation: should I train_test_split again or load test data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, train-test-split

Let's suppose I have a **train.py** file containing the logic for training a model and then saving its parameters into a directory called `weights/`:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
model = compile()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
model.save_weights("weights/")
```

Another file, namely **evaluate.py**, contains the logic for evaluating the performance of the model whose parameters will be loaded from the `weights/` directory:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
model = compile()
model.load_weights("weights/")
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

My question is: in the **evaluate.py** file, is the statement `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)` correct or am I supposed to load the same test set splitted in the **train.py** file? In that case the **train.py** file would be:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
np.save("x_test", x_test) 
np.save("y_test", y_test) 
model = compile()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
model.save_weights("weights/")
```

while the **evaluate.py** file would be:

```
x_test = np.load("x_test")
y_test = np.load("y_test")
model = compile()
model.load_weights("weights/")
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: The goal of train_test_split is to have a set of data never seen by the model for testing purposes, so yes you should use the same test set splitted in your first module

Comment: @AchilleG So the second version, with np.save and np.load, is the correct one?

Comment: yes definitly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simple way to deal with the evaluation model is to have train and test split data, on train dataset the model learn weights, then on evaluation stage you check model's metric on test data. You don't need to split data again in evaluate.py.
I also recommend specifying the random_state when splitting the dataset to achieve a reproducible result.

```
train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Using the np.load, then

Comment: No, what they are suggesting is to run `train_test_split` in both `train.py` and `evaluate.py` but with the identical `random_state`. That way you ensure that you will get the same train and test data in both calls to `train_test_split`, and you avoid saving and loading files.

Comment: @Anonymous This sounds clean